# Bash Autocomplete Package with IDE-like Feature

Tags: bash, ssh, software-recommendation, auto-completion

Using Ubuntu 20.04. I was wondering is there an open source package or extension that will make the bash terminal feel like an IDE with dynamic autocomplete suggestions while typing (without pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> and moving to the next prompt).

I have in mind something like this, as offered in any IDE.

[image: Screenshot from Atom Editor]

For example, when I type `git`, it should be pretty obvious it will be followed by `clone`, `stage` or `push` etc. Surfacing some suggestions around these, without pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> would be cool.

It will take more RAM than my KDE Konsole, but I can afford it for the improved productivity.

On a related note, if there is one for local shells, I would be very happy to have an SSH client (such as Remminna) offering the same feature on remote hosts as well.

Disclaimer: I did ask the question on software recs stackexchange, but did not get any response. Thought I would ask here because obviously this community is more targeted towards Ubuntu users.

Comment: There's https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete for zsh

Comment: Thanks, but Zshell is a different _language_ with a different syntax, right? Sorry, if the question is noob and may be it is a different question altogether. I know there are shells like fish, zsh etc. but do they run the same .sh scripts the same way as ubuntu terminal the only difference being graphical appearance?

Comment: You don't need to use zsh to run your scripts - they can continue to be run using bash or whatever shell you put in the shebang. Zsh supports most of bash's syntax, so while typing in an interactive shell you can pretend its bash to a great extent. Fish is rather different.